# Question regarding naming EEPROM

Tags: hardware, flash-memory

EEPROM stands for electronically erasable programmable read-only memory.

If it's erasable and programmable then why it's called read-only memory?
Question should suggest that I am new in all these topics, but wish to improve. Can someone shed some light on this topic?

Comment: This question does not belong here. Therefore I flag for moderator intervention to migrate.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because is total offtopic here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there's nothing specific to Unix/Linux here. Consider the scope of https://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Since i am new to stackexchange community & considering there are varying number of stack exchange forums available; its very difficult for someone new to find the right forum in first place. Rather then voting down (which is considered that poster has not done any research.. etc etc) is really a shame from moderators like you! You should have simply told me or guided me to the right forum! and not voted down my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [*dsstorefile*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/277591/dsstorefile1) noted [EEPROM is a “Read Only Memory,” so why can I write to it?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/243712) gives the hardware side of it.

The short **software** answer is:  this naming inconsistency reflects a widespread underlying taboo born of superstitious terror about breaking people's hardware.  This taboo probably causes more breakage than if there were no superstition.

---

In Unix, Linux, *et al*, slow, seldom used and seldom usable hardware memory devices like *PROM*, *EPROM* and *EEPROM* are the exception to ["Everything is a file"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Everything_is_a_file).

For example in *Linux* there's a plethora of different utils for writing to specific *EPROM* and *EEPROM* devices.  Run `apt show firmware` to see what's out there.  Each of these utils seems to have a *different command line interface* with a different dangerous learning curve, each with dire `man` page warnings about liability.   Collectively there's not much abstraction going on.

Lack of abstraction makes these utils *more* dangerous, because:

- there's less mindshare to scrutinize these utils' respective interfaces for bugs and defects than there would be if they shared a simpler common painstakingly protected interface.
- longer learning curves increase the likelihood that people will skip steps and thus inadvertently brick hardware.
- fear of bricking means many will neglect to update firmware that should be updated, which means more vulnerability to bugs, (and their attendant hacks).  Some bugs and hacks are *worse* than bricking.
- it reduces the odds of discovery if hardware vendors hide built-in spyware, malware, and backdoors.

Comment: Appreciate your help